# create custom size button in ionic

Tags: css, button, ionic-framework

I use the ionic framework and I'm trying to create a tab with 3 full width buttons that will cover the whole screen.I used the button-full option about width but how can i change the height?

**html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Rating">
    <ion-content>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced">
            What's good
        </button>
        <button class="button button-full button-assertive">
            What's bad
        </button>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive">
            Help us improve
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Override the Sass defaults if you want to change this for all buttons. If not, just add a custom style for `ion-view>ion-content>button.button.button-full` on this particular page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.button.customBtn{
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button-dark customBtn"> 
text </button>
```

---

This code worked for me when trying to set a fixed width to a button on an Ionic app.

Comment: Este es el Stack Overflow en Inglés. Sí no lo sabes escribir, mejor participar de [la versión en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

custom size may not be responsible if its is mandatory lets set style in that tag with height and width or create a css that will be more comfortable to use in all button with same format.

Comment: Better make a custom class just for those buttons